# Text logs with strange ^T delimiter being removed on read by Python

Tags: python-3.x, text, encoding, io, delimiter

I've got some logs with a strange delimiter, sample line here:

```
SomeMoreData^TSomeData^TSomeValue
```

The following sed command works in CLI to replace it with something more useful like a tab:

```
cat -A logs.txt | sed 's,\^T,\t,g'
```

When pasting the actual line on stackoverflow is removes the delimiter: SomeMoreDataSomeDataSomeValue

It looks like this (screenshot) [image]

The same happens when I'm reading the file with Python, the delimiter is ignored and thus renders parsing the logs impossible.

Here's my python code:

```
with open('logs.txt', 'r') as f:
    logs = [line.replace(r'^T', r'\t') for line in f]

print(logs[0]) # to display the first log
```

That outputs

```
SomeMoreDataSomeDataSomeValue
```

Instead of what I need:

```
SomeMoreData\tSomeData\tSomeValue
```

I looked at import io and tried UTF-8 with same effect, anyone come across this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^T` is a [ASCII control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) with a hex value of `0x14`. Try running the following code to observe it yourself:

```
str = "SomeMoreDataSomeDataSomeValue"
list(map(lambda c: hex(ord(c)), str))
```

I can't guess why would you have that value in your log, but you can make your python code work with this:

```
logs = [line.replace('\x14', '\t') for line in f]
```

Comment: I cannot discern why either! But on the plus side your suggestion worked.